# openssl: decryption output issue for aes ctr method in c for 128 bit key with 3gpp testvectors

Tags: c, linux, openssl

I am using openssl AES-CTR method for encryption/decryption with 128 bit key.
encryption is fine but i am not able to get original input after decryption.
i am testing 3GPP test vectors in linux environment in c.
I am getting below output:

```
    actual indata =
     fd40a41d 370a1f65 74509568 7d47ba1d 36d2349e 23f64439 2c8ea9c4 9d40c132 71aff264 d0f24800

    Enc indata =
     75750d37 b4bba2a4 dedb3423 5bd68c66 45acdaac a48138a3 b0c471e2 a7041a57 6423d292 7287f0f5


    decryption function is called

    Dec indata =
     c80f33a5 b884f2a4 489d2048 bc133a25 b9fad603 4c09f888 8ac7d546 1c359f1b f3c4ff3b b3bf19d1
```

Here after decryption output has to match to actual input data.But here i am unable to get proper output.
 can you please help in this regard.Thanks in advance.

```
    #include <openssl/aes.h>
    #include <openssl/rand.h>
    #include <openssl/hmac.h>
    #include <openssl/buffer.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <math.h>

    #define u32 unsigned int
    #define u8 unsigned char
    #define MAX_SIZE 2048
    #define BIT_SIZE 128
    #define INPUT_LENGTH   40  /*set 3*/

    struct ctr_state
    {
            unsigned char ivec[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];
            unsigned int  num;
            unsigned char ecount[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];
    };

    AES_KEY key;

    unsigned char indata[MAX_SIZE];
    unsigned char outdata[MAX_SIZE];
    unsigned char iv[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];
    struct ctr_state state;


    int init_ctr(struct ctr_state *state, const unsigned char iv[16])
    {
        /* aes_ctr128_encrypt requires 'num' and 'ecount' set to zero on the * first call. */
        state->num = 0;
        memset(state->ecount, 0, AES_BLOCK_SIZE);

        /* Initialise counter in 'ivec' to 0 */
        memset(state->ivec + 8, 0, 8);

        /* Copy IV into 'ivec' */
        memcpy(state->ivec, iv, 8);
    }


    void cipher_aes_128(const unsigned char *enckey, int count, int bearer, int dir, u8 *indata, int length )
    {
        int n,i,flag=1,n1,padbit,padded[16];

        n=length/BIT_SIZE;
        if(length%BIT_SIZE!=0)
        {
          flag=0;
          n=n+1;
        }

        printf("\nn=%d\n",n);
        iv[0] = (count >> 24) & 0xff ;
        iv[1] = (count >> 16) & 0xff ;
        iv[2] = (count >> 8)  & 0xff;
       iv[3] = count & 0xff;
       iv[4] = htonl((( (bearer << 27) | ((dir & 0x1) << 26))));
       iv[5] = iv[6]= iv[7] = 0;


      //Initializing the encryption KEY
      if (AES_set_encrypt_key(enckey, BIT_SIZE, &key) < 0)
       {
            printf(stderr, "Could not set decryption key.");
           exit(1);
       }

       init_ctr(&state, iv);//Counter call
        //Encrypting Blocks of 16 bytes and writing the output with ciphertext
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            AES_ctr128_encrypt(&indata[AES_BLOCK_SIZE*i], &outdata[AES_BLOCK_SIZE*i],AES_BLOCK_SIZE, &key, state.ivec, state.ecount, &state.num);
        }
        for(i=0;i<(AES_BLOCK_SIZE*n);i++)
        {
           indata[i] = outdata[i];
        }
        printf("\n");
    }


    void cipher_aes_128_decode(const unsigned char *enckey, int count, int bearer, int dir, u8 *indata, int length )
    {
            printf("\ndecryption function is called\n");
            cipher_aes_128(  enckey, count, bearer,  dir, indata, length );
            printf("\n");
    }


    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        /*Test data 3 */
     u8 key1[16] = {
            0x0a,0x8b,0x6b,0xd8,0xd9,0xb0,0x8b,0x08,
            0xd6,0x4e,0x32,0xd1,0x81,0x77,0x77,0xfb
      };
      u8 count[4] ={0x54,0x4d,0x49,0xcd };
      u32 tempCount = 0;
      u8 bearer = 0x04;
      u8 dir =0,i;
      u32 length = 310 ;
      u8 indata[INPUT_LENGTH] = {
            0xfd,0x40,0xa4,0x1d,0x37,0x0a,0x1f,0x65,
            0x74,0x50,0x95,0x68,0x7d,0x47,0xba,0x1d,
            0x36,0xd2,0x34,0x9e,0x23,0xf6,0x44,0x39,
            0x2c,0x8e,0xa9,0xc4,0x9d,0x40,0xc1,0x32,
            0x71,0xaf,0xf2,0x64,0xd0,0xf2,0x48,0x00
    };
      tempCount = htonl((count[0] | (count[1] << 8) | count[2]<< 16 | count[3] << 24));

      printf("actual indata =\n");
      for(i=0;i<INPUT_LENGTH;i++)
      {
         if((i%4)==0)
         printf(" ");
           printf("%02x",indata[i]);
      }

      cipher_aes_128( key1, tempCount, bearer,  dir, indata, length );

      printf("Enc indata =\n");
      for(i=0;i<INPUT_LENGTH;i++)
      {
         if((i%4)==0)
         printf(" ");
           printf("%02x",indata[i]);
      }
      cipher_aes_128_decode(key1,tempCount,bearer,dir,indata,length);

      printf("\nDec indata =\n");
      for(i=0;i<INPUT_LENGTH;i++)
      {
         if((i%4)==0)
         printf(" ");
           printf("%02x",indata[i]);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would recommend using different crypto library like [NaCl](http://nacl.cr.yp.to/) for C/C++ or [crypto++](http://www.cryptopp.com/) for C++ because they provide easier to implement primitives, in openssl it is easy to mess up implementation. Second I suggest reading [how to pick iv in ctr mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608489/how-to-pick-an-appropriate-iv-initialization-vector-for-aes-ctr-nopadding). Another thing is You are not incrementing counter each block.

I compiled code and my output is:

```
actual indata =
 fd40a41d 370a1f65 74509568 7d47ba1d 36d2349e 23f64439 2c8ea9c4 9d40c132 71aff264 d0f24800
n=3

Enc indata =
 75750d37 b4bba2a4 dedb3423 5bd68c66 45acdaac a48138a3 b0c471e2 a7041a57 6423d292 7287f0f5
decryption function is called

n=3



Dec indata =
 fd40a41d 370a1f65 74509568 7d47ba1d 36d2349e 23f64439 2c8ea9c4 9d40c132 71aff264 d0f2480
```

Comment: Thank you for the answers.while giving input to the decryption i am copying more than required data from encryption leading to decryption fails.now it is fine.I am having another query.after encryption key stream has to be genearated.but here it is generating direct cipher output.(keystream xor input) should be final cipher output.I dont know why without genearing keystream function directly giving final output.Thanks you very much Maciej for sharing answers. below is required key stream:8835a92a 83b1bdc1 aa8ba14b 2691367b 737eee32 87777c9a 9c4ad826 3a44db65 158c20f6 a275b8f5 0e8ae073 997c58ed